# Is there a way to use the SVM model (trained in matlab) in android studio?

Tags: android, matlab, svm

I am trying to combine data process with android app development. I have trained a svm model in matlab using libsvm, and the android app I am working on can obtain data features from a device. What I want is to use this svm model in android studio to predict the new data coming in. Is there a way to only **USE** the model instead of implement the entire svm algorithm is android studio? Thank you :)   p.s. The model is .mat file.

Comment: The `.mat` file is a proprietary Matlab format file, I reckon it is rather hard to open and read such files outside Matlab (Wolfram and R have some tricks though) unless you have Matlab installed on your android device :/ You may want to consider saving it in a more "open" format, such as .txt. This link may also help http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35138-read-mat-file-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a prediction you need to save the support vectors `x_i`, the associated dual variables (the signed `alpha`'s you get from `libsvmrtrain`) and the bias (`-rho` you get from `libsvmrtrain`). Then for making a prediction on a new sample `x`, you calculate:

[image: svm-predict]

where `K` is the kernel used for learning. Note that `libsvm` embeds the label `y_i` into the dual variables, so you can just use the `alpha`s.

The easiest way is to save all the variables you need to a text file (or some binary file you can easily read on the mobile device).

Comment: thank you! I'll try that :) could you give me the link where this formula comes from? I'm sure I've seen this before but can't remember what's those parameters represent...

Comment: It doesn't come from a link, it's just the SVM theory. The parameters alpha, rho, and xi are given in the output struct in Matlab after you call `svmtrain` in the fields `sv_coeff`, `rho`, and `SVs`, respectively

Comment: Oh! one more question, how to compute kernel function (the model I use is linear)? To put it another way, is ΣK(x,xi) = SVs' * x or ΣK(x,xi) = x' * SVs? I have multi dimension data.

Comment: when you use libsvm you have to pass an input argument to set the kernel, that's the `-t` option, if you don't then the default is the Gaussian kernel (aka RBF), so when you make a prediction you have to use the same kernel with the same parameters (the RBF has one parameter passed in by `-g`, it also has a default if you don't set it).